# redirect http to https in twisted

Tags: ssl, https, twisted

I'm running a django app using twisted. I moved now from http to https. How can I add redirects from http to https in twisted?

Comment: Please elaborate on how you are using Twisted to run your Django app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy way to generate redirects in Twisted Web is is with the [Redirect](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.util.Redirect.html) resource.  Instantiate it with a URL and put it into your resource hierarchy.  If it is rendered, it will return a redirect response to that URL:

```
from twisted.web.util import Redirect
from twisted.web.resource import Resource
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.internet import reactor

root = Resource()
root.putChild("foo", Redirect("https://stackoverflow.com/"))

reactor.listenTCP(8080, Site(root))
reactor.run()
```

This will run a server which responds to a request for http://localhost:8080/ with a redirect to https://stackoverflow.com/.

If you're running Django in the WSGI container hosted on an HTTPS server, then you might have code that looks something like this:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.wsgi import WSGIResource
from twisted.web.server import Site
from django import some_wsgi_application_object # Not exactly

root = WSGIResource(reactor, reactor.getThreadPool(), some_wsgi_application_object)
reactor.listenSSL(8443, Site(root), contextFactory)

reactor.run()
```

You can run an additional HTTP server which generates the redirects you want by just adding some of the code from the first example to this second example:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.wsgi import WSGIResource
from twisted.web.util import Redirect
from twisted.web.server import Site
from django import some_wsgi_application_object # Not exactly

root = WSGIResource(reactor, reactor.getThreadPool(), some_wsgi_application_object)
reactor.listenSSL(8443, Site(root), contextFactory)

old = Redirect("https://localhost:8443/")
reactor.listenTCP(8080, Site(old))

reactor.run()
```

Comment: Right, but for an HTTPS redirect, you want to redirect not to a fixed URL, but to a URL a) with whatever hostname or address the user entered and b) to the same path on the server that the user entered. (e.g. I would do this in apache mod_rewrite with `RewriteRule ^var/www-redirect/(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]`). Is this possible with a Redirect resource or some other way in twisted?

Comment: Er, my mod_rewrite example is for a redirect site with the document root `/var/www-redirect`. =)

Comment: Sure.  `Redirect` is actually a really simple class, <http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-11.0.0/twisted/web/util.py#L30>.  It can be extended to take the hostname from the request and use it in the redirect.  And you can look at `ChildRedirector` to see how to preserve the request path, too.

Answer (score 5):

To redirect from any given path on HTTP to the same path on the HTTPS
(based on Jean-Paul's suggestions in response to my comment):

```
from twisted.python import urlpath
from twisted.web import resource, util

class RedirectToScheme(resource.Resource):
    """
    I redirect to the same path at a given URL scheme
    @param newScheme: scheme to redirect to (e.g. https)
    """

    isLeaf = 0

    def __init__(self, newScheme):
        resource.Resource.__init__(self)
        self.newScheme = newScheme

    def render(self, request):
        newURLPath = request.URLPath()
        # TODO Double check that == gives the correct behaviour here
        if newURLPath.scheme == self.newScheme:  
            raise ValueError("Redirect loop: we're trying to redirect to the same URL scheme in the request")
        newURLPath.scheme = self.newScheme
        return util.redirectTo(newURLPath, request)

    def getChild(self, name, request):
        return self
```

Then you can use `RedirectToScheme("https")`, in place of your `Site()` for the HTTP site that you want to redirect from.

Note: If the HTTP that you want to redirect from is on a non-standard port, you will probably have a `:<port>` part in the the URLRequest that you'll also need to rewrite.

Comment: This used to work because redirectTo used to take its first argument (`newURLPath` here) and interpolate it into a string with `%s`.  However, more recent versions of Twisted have changed to doing something else.  It is now an error to pass a `URLPath` to `redirectTo`.  This kinda feels like a regression in Twisted - but `redirectTo` was documented as taking `str` before (now `bytes`).  So ... one could also argue this is a mis-use of the API.  Anyway, to make this work, you should smash `newURLPath` into a byte string before passing it to `redirectTo` - `bytes(newURLPath)`.

Comment: thanks for the useful writeup. One thing I changed was the `if newURLPath.scheme == self.newScheme` which worked for me. Could you explain why them not being equal would mean a Redirect loop?

Comment: @AmaJayJB yeah, that seems to be a mistake. I've made that change. Unfortunately I no longer have access to the project that I originally wrote this for so I can't look into the history of it.

Comment: absolutely no problem. Thought there was something I was missing (thanks for the reply!)